# Regular Expression for span text in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

html code

```
<span id="nameDomain">gmail.com</span>
```

How to take the field values in Regular Expression extractor of jmeter

What i have to give

Regular Expression:
Template:
Match No.(0 for Random):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the below example to extract the value.

You need to use `${spanval}` in the subsequent requests to access the value you have extracted.

[image]

Check this: [JMeter - Regular Expression 
Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Answer (score 0):

In general [using regular expressions to parse HTML isn't a very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748) as regular expressions are very sensitive to markup change and very fragile.

You can use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) instead.

1. Add XPath Extractor as a child of the request which returns that "span" and configure it as follows:

   - Check `Use Tidy` box if response is not [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML)-compliant
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `nameDomain`
   - XPath Query: `//span[@id='nameDomain']/text()`
2. Refer extracted value as `${nameDomain}` where required.

See [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) for language reference and [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for some more details.

---

If you still want to use Regular Expressions, the relevant Regular Expression will be `<span id="nameDomain">(\S+)</span>` and Template `$1$`. Other fields (apart from the "Reference Name" may be left as they are.